# Можно использовать 2 и больше файлов перевода в PyQt4?

Tags: python, локализация, python-2.x, pyqt4

Пытаюсь сделать мультиязычность и втыкаю уже третий день. Есть такой код в главном скрипте программы. Тут я вызываю главную форму.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    locale = QtCore.QLocale.system().name()
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(str(QtCore.QDir.currentPath()), "language", "user_" + str(locale) + ".qm")):
        translator = QtCore.QTranslator(app)

        translator.load("language/default_" + locale)
        translator.load("language/user_" + locale)
        # и теперь соответственно загружен только файл user_ru_RU.qm
        # Есть ли способ использовать 2 файла?

        app.installTranslator(translator)

    MainWindow = Ui_MainFormWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Есть ли способ использовать 2 файла?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все решилось просто. Меняем код на этот:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

locale = QtCore.QLocale.system().name()
if os.path.exists(os.path.join(str(QtCore.QDir.currentPath()), "language", "user_" + str(locale) + ".qm")):
    default_translator = QtCore.QTranslator(app)
    user_translator = QtCore.QTranslator(app)

    default_translator.load("language/default_" + locale)
    user_translator.load("language/user_" + locale)

    app.installTranslator(default_translator)
    app.installTranslator(user_translator)

MainWindow = Ui_MainFormWindow()
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

И все работает как надо )))